# bootstrap 3 does not apply panel-primary as blue background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/PwKzMJ

I use panel-primary but the background is not blue instead the border gets blueish...

Why this?

```
<div id="main-container" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
     <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Customer
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="http://s16.postimg.org/tqs90puwl/customer.png"></img>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-bottom">

               <ul class="list-group">
                 <li class="list-group-item ">Intel</li>
                 <li class="list-group-item ">Micron</li>
                 <li class="list-group-item ">Infineon</li>   
                 <li class="list-group-item ">First Solar</li> 
              </ul>

        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#main-container
{
  margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elisa

The codepen link added by you have two classes

```
.panel-primary {
  background-color: #006AB3 !important;
}
```

And

```
.panel .panel-footer{
  background:white;
}
```

As the **specificity** of panel-footer is more so it has been applied to the footer.
Try removing the .panel-footer class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.panel-primary {
background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
.panel .panel-footer{
  background: #006AB3;
}
```

Because your footer completely cover your panel :-)

Edited CodePen:- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPjRMQ